# Android sharedUserID Performance

Tags: android, android-manifest

I would like to know more about **sharedUserID** in android.

1. Is it safe to user sharedUserID in multiple applications? Because, I'm planning to use it for sharing user credentials.
2. Should the sharedUserID be same for the multiple applications? or can it be different?
3. Giving sharedUserID is used in multiple applications, will all the apps be run in same process? Will it affect the performance of the apps?

Answer (score 0):

1、if your apps have the same signatrue and the same sharedUserId,it is save. Because zhe signature is diffent for every company or personal.
2. apps been specified the same sharedUserId must have the same sharedUserId and the same signature.
3.if you specify the same process name in AndroidManifest.xml,they run in the same process,otherwise in the diffent one.if the apps run in the diffent process,there have no effect on the other app.